# Selection in Multi-Indexed DataFrame when key does not exists

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to use multi-indexed dataframe as dictionary to retrieve rows of interest in a fast manner. I'm using the .ix[] method to select a row by it's multi-index, but I encounter Exceptions when the key does not exists. Is there a way to get() rows with defualt return value? Or must I use a try-except combo to do what I need?

Example:

```
df = DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[1,2,3],'c':[1,2,3]})
df.set_index(['a','b'])

         c
a   b   
1   1    1
2   2    2
3   3    3
```

Now when trying `df.ix[1,5]` I get an exception, would like to get a default value.

**EDIT:**

Here is the reason for the question being asked in the first place. I have 2 big dataframes (one with 20,000 rows and the other with 500,000) rows. each row in both tables marks a word spotting event. the columns are "fileName", "Word", "startTime","endTime".

What Im trying to do is to figure out which event from the small df (df1) apears also in df2. The problem is that the timings in the two tables is different. For example:

```
df1

    fileName    Word    startTime   EndTime
0    file1   additional  149640  150310
1    file1   additional  316430  316900
2    file1   additional  174180  174640
3    file2   additional  161900  162460
4    file2   additional  97150   97600
```

and df2:

```
df2

    fileName    Word   startTime EndTime
0    file1   additional  149717  150406
1    file1   additional  316507  316996
2    file1   additional  174257  174736
3    file2   additional  201977  202556
4    file2   additional  97227   97696
```

You can see that events 0,1,2 and 4 are the same events, though the timings are slightly different. I consider them identical if their start and end times are similar to some small tolerance. the 3 event is not meeting that tolerance and thus should not be considered the same event.

My approach to do this task:

1. index the big dataframe (df2) by the fileName and Word columns.
2. iterate over the rows of df1 and for each row:

   - use the row fileName and Word values to select the appropriate subset in df2
   - iterate over the rows of the df2 subset and look for events that meeting the time tolerance
   - if such event was found in df2, return True. else return false.

I'll happily look into different approaches.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `get` (though it only works on the primary selection axis, e.g. in a frame its the columns), so you need to use the transpose to access.

```
In [23]: df = DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[1,2,3],'c':[1,2,3]})

In [24]: x = df.set_index(['a','b'])

In [25]: x
Out[25]: 
     c
a b   
1 1  1
2 2  2
3 3  3

[3 rows x 1 columns]

In [26]: x.T.get((1,1))
Out[26]: 
c    1
Name: (1, 1), dtype: int64

In [27]: x.T.get((1,5),default='foo')
Out[27]: 'foo'
```

However, generally iterating and selecting values is not an efficient method of doing things with frames. What is your end goal?

Comment: Here's an enhancement issue for this in any event (to be able to directly specify an axis): https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6703

Comment: I have 2 big dataframes holding events in time. An event is described by two attributes and start and end times. What I want to do is to locate similar events. Unfortunately, the times in both tables are not exacts. there can be some differences of milliseconds. So what Im doing is for each event from one table, find a small subset of similar events candidates in the other table by the two attributes, then Im checking the timings to decide whether I have a "close enough" event. To do the selection quickly, Im setting the attributes as indexes.

Comment: just do this then: ``df1[(df1.index>start_time_for_event)&(df1.index<end_time_for_event)]`` (do a reset_index to remove the non-time part of the index first)

Comment: Each row in the two df's contain filename, word, and timings when the word was spotted. I need to know whether the word spotted in one table are also spotted in the other. As mentioned the timings are different slightly. if I index by time as you suggested, I may mix different words and different filenames. for example if 2 different words were spotted in the same time in two different files, the code above will consider them identical events, which they are not.Thus I first need to get a subset of the target table by the filename and word attributes, and then look into the timings.

Comment: sounds like you need to groupby first

Comment: no, you need to do this on the entire frame, selecting out individual elements is general VERY slow. Try doing what I suggegted AFTER a groupby (e.g. in the apply function itself, which only has a time-index and only has the elements for which group you need)

Comment: Jeff, it seems like you are suggesting something very different from what I do, but yet I cant seem to follow your line of thought. say df1 and df2 contains events with the above attributes. what would be your workflow exactly? can you give me enumerated code lines? Im iterating over the rows of df1, use the row "fileName" and "Word" attributes to select a subset in df2 (which is pre indexed appropriately to save time) and then from the smaller dataframe, checks for identical events. Can you edit your answer and add the way you would do that?

Comment: well...maybe put up an example of your data set, what you are doing, and what you want as output, really quite difficult from words what you want

Comment: Jeff, do you approve the flow I had described or do you have different approach?